# XUL Testing Tools

Tags: firefox, testing, xul

Are there any tools for testing XUL? I'm using yui test for testing XPCOM. But I can't find any for XUL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [clear-code.com](https://www.clear-code.com/software/uxu/mozunit.en.png))</sub>

I am using [UxU,](https://web.archive.org/web/20191029185811/https://www.clear-code.com/software/uxu/index.html.en#start) which is a reworked version of [MozUnit](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328233959/http://hyperstruct.net:80/projects/mozunit). Though I was initially intimidated by the fact that its documentation is half in Japanese, I've used it for few hours and I already feel like recommending it!

Besides allowing you to test your javascript code within the same environment wherein it will run, it also provides a number of convenient [helpers methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20160402143324/http://www.clear-code.com/software/uxu/helpers.html.en#sample) to remote-control the browser and automating functionalities such loading URLs, opening Tabs, modifying preferences, accessing files and local storage..

Definitively worth of a try!

Comment: You say: it "allow[s] you to test your javascript code within the same environment wherein it will run", but this does not happen automatically! You have to call some helper methods to make it happen. http://www.clear-code.com/software/uxu/helpers.html.en#window